# Why I'm facing PROBLEM square detection in image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, detection, square

I'm trying to detect all RED marked square shapes in this [Desire Image box detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up8f7.jpg) and them in this showed RED square.
Here is my ORGINAL [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ6pm.jpg)

Here is the code I have got but it is missing some squares.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('Music/1.bmp')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(blur, -1, sharpen_kernel)

thresh = cv2.threshold(sharpen,160,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

min_area = 100
max_area = 1500
image_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > min_area and area < max_area:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(image_number), ROI)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        image_number += 1

cv2.imshow('sharpen', sharpen)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**And here is my [OUTPUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPIn7.jpg):**
Please, help me how I can predict the missing square positions based on recognized squares? Or can we modify the above algorithm for the square detection algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

First, `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` is the wrong algorithm for finding grid squares.  It finds separated regions, not connected regions.  Change that to `cv2.RETR_TREE`.

Second, your min/max values are way too small.  Those squares are about 1/12 of the page width, which means the squares will be about 120x120, which is an area of 14,400.  So, set

```
min_area = 10000
max_area = 15000
```

With those two changes, I manage to get about half of the squares.  Doing better is probably a matter of refining your blur, sharpen, and threshold parameters to get stronger grid lines.

On the other hand, you could take the squares you DO find and interpolate the grid from that.  You know what the pattern is.